# Combinatorial proof of $\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{m+k-i-1}{k-i}\binom{n+i-1}{i}=\binom{m+n+k-1}{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Please provide a combinatorial proof for the following:

Prove the identity $$\sum_{i=0}^{k}{m+k-i-1 \choose k-i}{n+i-1 \choose i}={m+n+k-1 \choose k}$$

*Hint*: use idea of "selection with repetition".

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{m+k-i-1}{k-i}\binom{n+i-1}{i}=\binom{m+n+k-1}{k}\quad?$$ What did you try to do?

Comment: Yes I that's the question. For the R.S I said that its counts the no. of ways to select k objects from m+n objects with repetition, but am not sure how to interpret the summation side.

Comment: It looks like a homework problem.

Comment: @JoeZeng: or an exercise in a book. It's hard to second guess. In cases like this, without further information, we usually accept what the author says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine you have $m$ red objects and $n$ blue objects, and you want to select $k$ objects with possible repetitions. This can be done (as you stated yourself in the comment) in

$$\binom{m+n+k-1}{k}$$

different ways.

On the other hand, among these $k$ selected objects, there could be exactly $k$ red ones and $0$ blue ones, there could be $k-1$ red and $1$ blue, etc. Each of these cases are mutually exclusive, and there are

$$\binom{m+(k-i)-1}{k-i} \binom{n+i-1}{i}$$

ways to choose exactly $k-i$ red objects and $i$ blue objects. Sum over all $i$ and you get your identity.

Comment: @Sarah: You're welcome! And since you're new here, don't forget to upvote answers and questions you find useful (and not just answers to your own questions). If you're really happy with a particular answer, you can "accept" it, but it's usually a good idea to wait awhile before doing that -- even better answers can appear later.

Comment: Yes for sure! But how do I upvote?

Comment: @Sarah: Look at the grey arrows in the left column. Clicking the up-arrow gives an upvote, and likewise, the down-arrow gives a downvote. The number attached to each post is the difference between upvotes and downvotes.